# SQL - Both criteria match therefore count

Tags: sql

I am trying to split my search from the database into multiple criteria however I seem to be pulling the wrong data.

```
sum(case when date between '2019-12-01' and '2019-12-31' then 1 else 0 end) Dec19,
sum(case when service like 'A%' or  service like 'B%' and date between '2019-12-01' and '2019-12-31' then 1 else 0 end) DecAB,
sum(case when service like 'C%' or service like 'D%' and date between '2019-12-01' and '2019-12-31' then 1 else 0 end) DecCD,
sum(case when service like 'E%' or service like 'E%' or service like 'F%' and date between '2019-12-01' and '2019-12-31' then 1 else 0 end) DecEF,
```

However, issue in hand now is...while this SQL script can run but the total sum of the bottom 3 lines is more than the first line. Which shouldn't be the case, as I am just trying to split the total of the first line for better in-detailed analysis.

In case that I am not clear, I am trying to find the total of count of booking for service A and B for the month of Dec, so on and so far. While the first time is the total count of booking.

Comment: Can you add some sample data? Also please tag appropriate database name.

Answer (score 1):

I would put parentheses around the OR statements to be sure they are handled correctly, `(service like 'A%' or  service like 'B%')` together with the AND condition. Right now it says "give me all service like 'A%'but only service like 'B%' for the date period"

And you have a duplicate OR in your last row.